# Plot world map with color gradient associated to numeric values in ggplot2

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

I have a dataset (turbidity) with coordinates info and a turbidity value associated with each point on the map.

| Lat | Long | unit | values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -27.33 | -55.92 | NTU | 78.94 |
| -28.33 | -55.92 | NTU | 98.22 |
| -29.33 | -55.92 | NTU | 78.94 |
| -27.33 | -55.92 | NTU | 98.22 |
| 33.7 | 103.65 | NTU | 1123 |
| 33.8 | 103.65 | NTU | 1123 |
| 33.9 | 103.65 | NTU | 1123 |
| 34.1 | 103.65 | NTU | 1123 |
| 34.2 | 103.65 | NTU | 1123 |
| 34.3 | 103.65 | NTU | 197 |
| 34.5 | 103.65 | NTU | 197 |

What I´m trying to do is to plot a map with ggplot2 showing this range of values associated with a place on the map.

Here´s an example

[image]

I tried many solutions pointed at the internet but none worked with my code and dataset.

Here´s the code I´m using:

```
world <- map_data("world")
options(ggrepel.max.overlaps = Inf)
ggplot() +
  geom_map(data = world, map = world,aes(long, lat, map_id = region),color = "white", fill = "gray", size = 0.1)+
  scale_fill_continuous(data=turbidity, values=colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, 'Reds'))(length(turbidity$values)))+
  labs(title = "")+
  scale_color_viridis_d(option = "plasma")+
  xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude")+
  theme(legend.title= element_blank())
```

Can anyone point a solution?

Comment: Try adding something like `+ geom_point(data = name_of_your_data_frame, aes(fill = value))` to your plot.

Comment: `scale_fill_continuous` sets up the range of colors used, but doesn't actually plot anything. If you want points on your map, use `geom_point()`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am actually looking for a "fill" aesthetic, not points. What function can I use?

Comment: Well, the data you show looks like point data, not polygon data. What do you want to fill?

Comment: Yes, that´s right. Maybe reducing point size will make it look like all the points together are covering the map area.

Comment: You could use `geom_contour` to estimate a smooth filled surface using the points, but I don't know how well that would work with a map projection. Probably better to use a spatial analysis package for something like that.

Comment: That sounds too advanced for me, but just as a curiosity, what kind of package would that be? Any examples?

Comment: I'm not really up on spatial analysis, you can see the [CRAN Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html) for a good overview. For something like that, I'd look in `sf` first, and if I didn't find it there I'd try `terra` or maybe `rgdal`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you please post a minimal dataset into the question using `dput(data)`, say for a small island to make the question reproducible.

Comment: My dataset is not complete, but the example that I showed in the question is a representative part of it. Hope it is useful.